# How to get initramfs libraries for 32 and 64 bit using yocto

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using yocto for creating initramfs and it creates initramfs and places the libraries in lib directory.

I want to generate libraries for both 32 and 64 bit using yocto. In machine.conf I enabled MACHINE_FEATURES += "x86_64"

How I generate binaries for both 32 and 64 bit using yocto in initramfs

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure [multilib build](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#combining-multiple-versions-library-files-into-one-image). Basically that boils down to something like this in your local.conf:

```
MACHINE = "qemux86-64"

require conf/multilib.conf
MULTILIBS = "multilib:lib32"
DEFAULTTUNE_virtclass-multilib-lib32 = "x86"
```

And then you use `lib32-${PN}` for 32-bit package variants in images, like let's say you want to have 32-bit dropbear package included:

```
 IMAGE_INSTALL = "packagegroup-core-boot ${ROOTFS_PKGMANAGE_BOOTSTRAP} lib32-dropbear"
```