# yocto Jethro: how to define a machine which build kernel in 64 bit whereas user space in 32bit

Tags: yocto

For reference I looked up the default provided machine conf files inside poky/meta.

Following seems to build qemuarm for 32bit, i.e. both kernel and user space 32bit

> http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/machine/qemuarm.conf?h=jethro

And following seems to  build qemuarm64 for 64 bit, i.e. both kernel and user space 64bit

> http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/machine/qemuarm64.conf?h=jethro

I need an example conf file for arm such that userspace is 32 bit but the kernel is built 64bit.

Comment: Don't think you can do that, Just compile the kernel and rootfs separately.  Btw, " I need an example conf file" without a proper question is irritating,  it sounds like you are a boss asking for content.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for the help.
Sorry for asking my question the wrong way.

Comment: I think you can do that with multilib [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271509/), although it won't be convenient because of the need to prefix your installed packages with `lib32-`. Probably there is a way to mangle some flags in a way that 32-bit versions will become the default (at the very minimum, you can change CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS to contain `-m32`), but that likely to cause some breakage and require quite some time to fix it.

Comment: @RomanKhimov thanks for your suggestion. I will try this approach out.